# .get XML data not working in Internet Explorer 7 or 8

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, internet-explorer

My jQuery code to Get XML data is not working in IE 7 or IE 8, it works in IE9 and everything else. I am not sure why this would be happening. Any help is greatly appreciated! I am working in Drupal so I am using jQuery instead of the $ sign. I am also very new to programming, so any advice is wonderful.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
   jQuery.get('/xml/designs.xml',function(data){

             jQuery(data).find('slide').each(function(){

                    var slide = jQuery(this);
                    var caption = slide.find('caption').text();
                    var source = slide.find('source').text()
                    var html = '<li class="mySlides"><a href="' + caption + '_Letterpress_Wedding_Invitation"><img src="/sites/aerialist.localhost/files/images/selectThumbs/' + source + '.jpg"/><p>' + caption + '</p><a>';     
                     var htmlPad = '<li class="mySlides"><a href="' + caption + '_Letterpress_Wedding_Invitation"><img src="/sites/aerialist.localhost/files/images/selectThumbs/' + source + '600.jpg"/><p>' + caption + '</p><a>';    

                    if (window.devicePixelRatio > 1) {

                     jQuery('#list').append(htmlPad);
                       jQuery('#list').hide();
                    jQuery('#list').fadeIn(800);

    } else {

        jQuery('#list').append(html);
                       jQuery('#list').hide();
                    jQuery('#list').fadeIn(800);
}

        });
        return false;
    })
});
```

Comment: Open the Developer Tools in IE8 to see what's going on. F12.

Comment: IE hates invalid html... the `LI` tags aren't closed and I would test to see if `window.devicePixelRatio` is legit in older IE versions simply because I'm not familiar with what it is

Answer (score 0):

As  charlietfl said, the problem is invalid HTML, but the problem is not the unclosed `<li>` (it's valid HTML, `<li>`-elements don't need to be closed), the problem are the `<a>`'s at the end of `html` and `htmlPad`, they have to be `</a>`

Comment: Fixing the HTML did the trick. I feel like an idiot for missing that. Thanks Guys!!!